# Not only DID he exceed/he EXCEEDED, but he HAD also drank alcohol. (Past tense)

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

How come sentence1 is more correct than sentence2, in terms of BETTER FIT with its relative clause?

> 1. Not only **DID** he exceed the speed limit, but he **HAD** also drank alcohol. (From a website)

Vs.

> 2. Not only he **EXCEEDED** the speed limit, but he **HAD** also drank alcohol. (My construction)

**Both** *introductory* *clause* (sentence 1 & 2) are in the **past**, aren't they? BUT, how come, if I were to construct a sentence, the sentence#2 would be incorrect?

[image]

Source: [Grammaring: Test your grammar #47](https://www.grammaring.com/english-grammar-test)
(scroll to reach #47)

Comment: Read this article: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/not-only-but-also

Comment: "had drank" is correct? Anyway, I would phrase it "Not only did he exceed the speed limit, but he also had been drinking alcohol."

Comment: @MichaelRybkin, thx for the site, I have learned another style of using the "not only, but also" thingy, but my question is not about the usage of it. My bad, that's why I have edited the question just now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85636/discussion-between-john-arvin-and-duckisaduckisaduck).

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck, please see the attached picture above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither sentence is grammatical—or at least stylistically acceptable based on parallelism.

They can be made grammatical if you rephrase them:

> Not only **did** he exceed the speed limit, but he [] also **drank** alcohol.
>   He not only **exceeded** the speed limit, but he [] also **drank** alcohol.

If you want to keep *had* you will need to make some different changes:

> Not only **had he exceeded** the speed limit, but he **had also** ***drunk / had also been drinking*** alcohol.
>   He **had not only exceeded** the speed limit, but he **had also** ***drunk*** alcohol.

---

After addressing the construction of the sentences, there is really no essential difference between them in terms of meaning. (And after addressing the issue with parallelism, the second sentence is not incorrect.)

However, the first version in the question *can* be interpreted as having a sense of something habitual rather than referring to a one-time event.

Comment: Nice spot there in terms of parallelism, however, my question is about the introductory clause. What is the difference between the two? Between a *website's sentence* (sentence1) and my *construction* (sentence2) because I can't see any **difference** there. I wonder...

Comment: @JohnArvin I have updated my answer to address a possible difference in meaning between the two.

Comment: (>.<) maybe the grammar website has set-up a fixed situation.

Comment: "Not only did he exceed the speed limit but he had also  consumed alcohol" [prior to exceeding the speed limit] is grammatical. You do not need the past perfect in both clauses. "He exceeded the speed limit but he also had consumed alcohol".